# ? x : y, what is the meaning of that?

Tags: c#, .net

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 5, 7, 10 };
int number = 9;

int closest = list.Aggregate((x,y) => 
    Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number) ? x : y);
```

? x : y, what is the meaning of that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it's the equivalent of

```
if Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number) then use x else use y
```

See the MSDN documentation ([old version](http://web.archive.org/web/20160810143252/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(VS.80).aspx) / [new version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)) for more details and examples

Answer (score 7):

It is a [ternary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) operator. It encapsulates an `if-else-return` in one line.

Comment: ternary just means 3 parts! (akin to unary and binary). It's more accurately known as the conditional operator.

Comment: I have said it is `a` ternary operator and not it is `the` ternary operator. The links takes them to the operator.

Answer (score 5):

That is the [C# conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

It will allow you to specify a condition and two expressions. When the condition is true, the first expression is returned.  When it's false, the second expression is returned.  In this case, you are using this as the condition:

```
Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number)
```

When this is true, `x` is returned, when false, `y`.  The lambda created above is effectively the same as writing:

```
int closest = list.Aggregate((x,y) => 
    {
        if (Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number))
            return x;
        else
            return y;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a  little more to it than `? x : y`

What you see is called a ternary operator and is basically shorthand for a classic if/else statement. A ternary operator takes the following form:

```
<boolean_expression> ? <value_to_use_if_true> : <value_to_use_if_false>
```

In your case the boolean expression is:

```
 Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number)
```

And, if this expression is evaluated as true, you will get the value of:

```
x
```

Otherwise you will get:

```
y
```

Answer (score 2):

`a ? b : c` is a ternary operator, it translates to:

```
if(a)
    b;
else
    c;
```

Comment: However `b` and `c` are not statements, but expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator `?` - if condition on LHS of `?` is true, returns `x` - if condition false, returns `y`

Answer (score 1):

That is the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a)

BoolOpeartor ? TrueEval : FalseEval;

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as:

```
if (Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number)) 
    return x; 
else 
    return y;
```

Answer (score 0):

its a [ternary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) operator

```
if(Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number))
  true
else
  false  

        .
```

> Or simply

```
Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number) ? x : y
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 5, 7, 10 };
int number = 9;
int closest = list.Aggregate((x,y) => Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number) ? x : y);
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 5, 7, 10 };
int number = 9;
int closest = list.Aggregate((x,y) => 
{
    if(Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number))
    {
        return x;
    }
    else
    {
        return y;
    }
});
```

What you're using is called the conditional operator, which is a shorthand notation for an if-else statement, where the result returned is chosen as follows: **{true/false condition} ? {value if true} : {value if false}**